# dynamic image path within a javascript file

Tags: themes, customization

I need to dynamic the image path to my theme file within a javascript file. How would I go about this?

```
address.forEach(function(address){
   var markerGeoCoder;

   markerImage = {url: window.mr_variant == undefined ? 'img/mapmarker.png' : '../img/mapmarker.png', size: new google.maps.Size(50,50), scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50,50)};
   if(/(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)/.test(address) ){
       var latlong = address.split(','),
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: { lat: 1*latlong[0], lng: 1*latlong[1] },
           map: map,
           icon: markerImage,
           title: markerTitle,
           optimised: false
       });
   }
```

I already tried this :

```
address.forEach(function(address){
    var markerGeoCoder;

    markerImage = {url: window.mr_variant == undefined ? '<?php the_field('img/mapmarker.png'); ?>' : '../img/mapmarker.png', size: new google.maps.Size(50,50), scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50,50)};
    if(/(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)/.test(address) ){
        var latlong = address.split(','),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: 1*latlong[0], lng: 1*latlong[1] },
            map: map,
            icon: markerImage,
            title: markerTitle,
            optimised: false
        });
    }
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Is your script in a `<script></script>` tag in a template, or in a .js file that you're enqueueing?

Comment: r in a .js file

Answer (score 0):

If you're in JS you can't use PHP (`<?php ?>`), you need to another way to get a PHP variable into JS. The normal way with WordPress is to use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).

```
wp_localize_script( 'wpse_274344', 'myScriptObject', array(
    'markerImageUrl' => get_theme_file_uri( '/img/mapmarker.png' ),
) );
```

Add that code after your call to `wp_enqueue_script()` or `wp_register_script()`. Replace `wpse_274344` with the name you used when enqueuing the script.

This means that WordPress will output a JavaScript object named `myScriptObject` to the page containing the values that you passed to `wp_localize_script()`.

Then in your script file you can access the `markerImageUrl` like this:

```
markerImage = {
    url: window.myScriptObject.markerImageUrl
}
```